# The benefit of writing Banach space theory in categorical language!

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory

I was wondering if there exists a special benefit of writing Banach space theory in categorical language? I mean does there arise a hint of the existence of a connection with other mathematical field which one could not find out by expressing this theory in the usual form?

Comment: The notion of exact sequence is very much a concept of category theory, and in Banach space theory you may relate it to `Three-space problems'. You may want to have a look at "Three-space Problems in Banach Space Theory" by J. Castillo and M. Gonzalez.